# How to trigger catalyst optimizer before spark-submit to reduce execution time?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The organisation I am working on is moving to public cloud from their old traditional way of execution. we have to pay for all executions that takes place over the cloud. for reducing this execution cost, we are doing two things:

1. we are trying to avoid all bad execution.
2. we are trying to reduce the execution time further.

As a big data engineer, my work mostly depends on SparkSQL and I am trying to reduce the SQL query execution time. what catalyst do at execution time, I want to do that before the execution. for ex- reading the logical plan, optimizing the logical plan and generating the physical plan etc.
I also want to add my custom optimization plans in catalyst which will also be triggered at build time.

Is there any way to do all this before execution?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get the execution plan for your query by creating the dataframe and not performing any action.

Suppose you have a DataFrame `df`, you can access `df.logicalPlan` and traverse over the plan. This might answer your first requirement of avoiding bad execution, if you have some heuristic method to detect it.

As for custom optimizations, you can add your own optimization rules (see https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/introduction-custom-optimization-apache-spark-sql/read).
This does not trigger at build time, rather at execution time (like all catalyst optimizations)

Comment: BTW, you could also invoke the optimizer yourself:
`df.sparkSession().sessionState().optimizer().execute(df.logicalPlan());`

Comment: I know we can check a plan before spark execution by calling the explain() method but catalyst to do a lot and I wanted to do all its steps.for example, catalyst performs some rule-based transformations over the tree and generate the optimized logical plan. convertl ogical plan to a multiple physical plans and then uses the most optimised physical plan. can we do all that before execution so that catalyst have to do a little work at runtime